# Editing runtime classpath in IntelliJ to include src/main/config

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

I have writing a Java application in IntelliJ 12 using Maven and Spring. I have the following folders:

**src/main/java** : for Java code

**src/main/resources**: for resources to be packaged into final built JAR

**src/main/config**: for external resources, i.e. the spring configuration file.

I have tried making the src/main/config a sources folder, however, upon running my application, it fails with a FileNotFoundException on the following line:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
```

`spring-config.xml` sits inside **src/main/config**.

Also, I have noticed this file does not get copied over to the target directory that intelliJ produces when 'Make' building the project.

For now I am resorting to using a FileBasedApplicationContext for testing, however it would be nice to be able to run the application from within intelliJ without having to edit the code.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like this should work. That said, by convention, I'd use src/main/resources, which is the standard Maven config  directory, lexically because it's *not* an external resource : it's on the classpath.  If it's  there only for testing then it belongs in the test directory, if it's only for running inside IntelliJ I'd specify it via the run config and use a trivial custom configurator.

Answer (score 5):

See [my comment here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97759#comment=27-441982). Resource directories/patterns must be explicitly defined in your `pom.xml` file like this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: You have not answered my question at all. I am trying to maven build the project. I want to run my application in intelliJ so that I can debug it. In terms of the maven build, I will use the assembly plugin to create a bundle containing the built JAR, its dependencies and this external spring file.

Comment: IDEA build uses Maven information to find out what files it should include in classpath. If your pom defines resources in some unusual or not yet supported by IDEA way, it will not work. The workaround is to [disable external build](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png) in which case IDEA will use `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns` to copy additional files from the source folders. But it's a hack that you should avoid and describe all the resources in the pom file instead.

Comment: Is there any fixes for a gradle based project. Mine is not including resouces at all.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685813/classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener-in